# Visualizing 3D position and roll pitch yaw data

Tags: plotting, visualization

What is a way to visualize 3D trajectory data that contains a set of (x,y,z) coordinates that also contains pitch roll yaw (Alpha,Beta,Gamma) angles?

Comment: `Graphics3D` with `Point` and `Arrow` will help you

Comment: This could be useful to others and to me. Please could  you  post your answer as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Look up [`Graphics3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html) if you haven't yet, and study creating basic graphics.
2. Construct an object that is suitable for representing 3D rotations (e.g. a small triangle or even an aeroplane). Mathematica comes with multiple 3D objects built-in, such as `ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "SpaceShuttle"}]`. You might want to use them.  Extract the primitives using `ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "SpaceShuttle"}, "GraphicsComplex"]`
3. Create a rotation matrix from pitch/roll/yaw values using [`EulerMatrix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EulerMatrix.html).
4. Use [`GeometricTransformation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation.html) in `Graphics3D` as `GeometricTransformation[object, {rotationMatrix, translation}]`.
5. You can use multiple `{matrix, translation}` pairs in a list in `GeometricTransformation`, so you can easily visualize the object in one go at several time points. Use `Line` to draw the trajectory in the same scene.

Comment: Thank you @Szabolcs, works great!